# Install ASP.NET application on IIS on Windows Server 2019

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2019

I try to install an ASP.NET application to IIS on Windows Server 2019.

The application is built against NET 4.7.1, and it works just fine on IIS in Windows Server 2012 and 2016.

However, when I try to install it on new server running Windows Server 2019, the problems starts from the configuration phase.

Specifically:

- I copy the app with all the files in a folder on new server (2019)
- I create the appPool, using ApplicationIdentity, enable 32 bit access
- I create the web application, set to path the folder, set the appPool
  to my newly created apppool
- I set the permissions to read / write access for IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool

But I cannot even do any further configuration in IIS Management.

When I try to edit any config option (default page, etc, etc) IIS manag gaves me error that it cannot access the web.config file

I even set temporarily access rights to web app's folder to full access for everyone (!!!) - no success.

Any idea what can be?

Comment: DefaultAppPool is already in IIS? Did you create a duplicate?

Comment: "I create the appPool, using ApplicationIdentity". That new pool has its own identity account, not `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`, so you just assigned the wrong permissions and caused the issue, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: What is your error message ? and where it appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that was an error with creating the VPS image.

I recreated it and after that everything went ok

Answer (score 0):

Check .NET Version 2.0 or 4.0 . Classic or Integrated.

If your application is built on 32 bit platform. Set the Application Pool Advanced Setting  32 Bit Application to Enable.